# LocationSettingsRequest request does not work on Xiaomi

Tags: android, location, location-services

I try to show popup for users who have turned off Location Services:

```
val locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
        .setInterval(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1))
        .setFastestInterval(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1))
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
    val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest)
    LocationServices
        .getSettingsClient(this)
        .checkLocationSettings(builder.build())
        .addOnSuccessListener(this) { response: LocationSettingsResponse? ->
            
        }
        .addOnFailureListener(this) { ex ->
            if (ex is ResolvableApiException) {
                // Location settings are NOT satisfied,  but this can be fixed  by showing the user a dialog.
                try {
                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),  and check the result in onActivityResult().
                    val resolvable = ex as ResolvableApiException
                    resolvable.startResolutionForResult(
                        this,
                        REQUEST_CODE_CHECK_SETTINGS
                    )
                } catch (sendEx: SendIntentException) {
                    // Ignore the error.
                }
            }
        }
```

This code piece works very well for Samsungs, but whenever a user with XIAMO REDMI NOTE 10 tests it, popup does not appear.

Comment: Is there a play store in Xiaomi device?  as LocationRequest is a part  a google play services/

Comment: Have check out the google sample projects? There are some good examples if you like to read the code. I work in tracking/navigation section and google samples always have best examples and best practises. Check these, they might help you https://github.com/android/location-samples/tree/main/LocationUpdatesBackgroundKotlin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The pop up does not appear" is not really an error description, EUR 200 would be a physical device. They likely run Android 11 with [MIUI 12.5](https://en.miui.com/v12_5) ... while most cloud testing is Xiaomi Redmi Note 7, with Android 9. Reports suggest, to at least update the state-owned GPS-A IP address:

> Hi, just found that the supl server in the Location/A-GPS settings is set to a Chinese ip address (`221.176.0.55`, resolves to `chinamobile.com`)
> I guess it's a remnant from the China rom, for Europe it should probably be set to `supl.google.com` or perhaps `supl.vodafone.com`.

- Search for "A-GPS" in the settings.
- Replace A-GPS server `221.176.0.55` with `supl.google.com`.

---

It may well be, that Google Play Services aren't installed. In such case one can only build as a separate product flavor, targeting these devices in particular eg. with `googleImplementation` using `LocationRequest`, `xiaomiImplementation` using whatever location provider available.
Being able to run Google Maps or Google Earth is no problem, but this does not imply Google Play Services would also be installed - as they'd be required for location and push notifications.

---

According to some "authoritative source", GMS aren't banned on Xiaomi:

https://twitter.com/Xiaomi/status/1354489349442691074

But they cannot be assumed to be available either (by default).

---

You might be looking for "Fused Location Provider by Xiaomi Inc." aka `com.xiaomi.location.fused`, instead of `com.android.location.fused`. `com.android.internal.R.array.config_locationProviderPackageNames` is being used for lookup.